# how to get cumulative sum for groups

Tags: mysql

I have a table with an `id_visit`, `id_visitor`, and `SumOfTime`.

The `id_visitor` can have more than one id.

Time is already created with

```
SELECT idvisit, idvisitor, SUM(time) AS SumOfTime
FROM tbl1
GROUP BY idvisit, idvisitor
```

I would like to create an additional row, where I group the totals according to `idvisitor`. How can I do that?

Comment: WITH ROLLUP???? - although I prefer to handle this stuff in application code